# Self referential many-to-many hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation using association table:

Object:

```
Foo
id;
name
Set<Foo> dependencies;
```

Main table:

```
Foo      
id
name
```

Association table

```
foo_rel
parent_id <fk to Foo.id> 
child_id <fk to Foo.id>
```

In my Foo.hbm.xml I have the following

```
<set name="dependencies" table="foo_rel" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="none" >
                <key column="parent_id" />
                <many-to-many column="child_id" class="Foo"  />
 </set>
```

The problem is that whenever I create 2 new Foo objects having the same dependent Foos the foo_rel table is updated so it only holds the associations for the latest Foo object.

All I need is to have the self referential relationships between Foo and itself held in the associations table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this. To answer my own question:

I was calling `previousFoo.dependencies.clear()` in some method just before I save the object.